# How to check in which interval the value is?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to check whether User has enough karma (reputation) to have a permission to make an action (place a bid on item). The karma has is some value in an interval [-25; 100]. Also, as the user has more karma points, the time between the two bids by user gets shorter.

The implementation I have now is this:

```js
      if ((user.karma) > -14 && (user.karma) < -6) {
        throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma });
      }

      if ((user.karma) > -5 && (user.karma) < 5 && timePassed < 90) {
        throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: 90 });
      }

      if ((user.karma) > 6 && (user.karma) < 15 && timePassed < 45) {
        throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: 45 });
      }

      if ((user.karma) > 16 && (user.karma) < 29 && timePassed < 30) {
        throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: 30 });
      }

      if ((user.karma) > 30 && (user.karma) < 39 && timePassed < 20) {
        throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: 20 });
      }

      ...
```

Is there any neater way to check if the user.karma is in some interval AND if enough time has passed? The plan is to use larger interval of karma points, so this if tree does not look okay for performance reasons.

I have found a way to do this with `bisect` but I am not sure whether it is worth to implement it.

So, is there any other way to make this faster?

Comment: Do you mean faster to write the code or faster to execute the code?

Comment: Is your logic meant to skip certain values (-5, 5,15, 30 etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any neater way to check if the user.karma is in some interval AND if enough time has passed?

Yes, store the rules in a list of rules and check them all in 1 go rather than re-write the `if` statement for each one

```
const rules = [
  {minKarma:-14,maxKarma:-6,timeNeededToPass:Number.MAX_INTEGER},
  {minKarma:-5,maxKarma:5,timeNeededToPass:90},
  {minKarma:6,maxKarma:15,timeNeededToPass:45},
  {minKarma:16,maxKarma:29,timeNeededToPass:30},
  {minKarma:30,maxKarma:39,timeNeededToPass:20}
]

const foundRule = rules.find(r => user.karma > r.minKarma && user.karma < r.maxKarma && timePassed < r.timeNeededToPass);
if(foundRule) {
    throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: foundRule.timeNeededToPass });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have map of ranges (unless you can think of clever algorithm between karma points and time) and then just loop it:

```js
var karmaMap = [
  {min: -14, max: -6, time: null},
  {min: -5, max: 5, time: 90}
];

var user = {karma: -12}
var timePassed = 100

for (karmaRule of karmaMap) {
  if (user.karma > karmaRule.min && user.karma < karmaRule.max && (karmaRule.time === null || timePassed < karmaRule.time)) {
      //throw errors.create('NotAvailable', { karma: user.karma, timePassed, timeNeededToPass: 90 });
      throw 'Karma too small to perform KarmaAction'
  }
}
```